# UnboundLocalError while returning

Tags: python

Here's a simple code for linear curve fitting.

```
def cf(x, y):
    a0 = 0
    a1 = 0
    if (len(x) == len(y)) and (len(x) > 3):
        s_x = 0
        s_y = 0
        s_xsq = 0
        s_xy = 0
        i = 0
        while i < len(x):
            s_x += x[i]  
            s_y += y[i]
            s_xsq += x[i] ** 2
            s_xy += x[i] * y[i]
            i += 1
        a0 = (s_xsq * s_y - s_x * s_xy) / (len(x) * s_xsq - s_x ** 2)
        a1 = (len(x) * s_xy - s_x * s_y) / (len(x) * s_xsq - s_x ** 2)
    return a0, a1

xx = list(input("Enter x variables:"))
yy = list(input("Enter y variables:"))
m, c = cf(xx, yy)
print(m, c)
```

It compiles(or rather, interprets) without any problem but when I enter the values for `xx=[4,5,6,7]` and `yy=[10,12,14,16]`, it shows `UnboundLocalError:a0 is referenced before assignment`.

I read a lot of posts regarding that over here(and on a few other sites as well) wherein in coralmost every case, variables are declared outside the `def`, which is not the case here. I also saw a case similar to mine, where variables are declared inside the while loop and the suggestion was to declare the variables outside while. I tried that and yet the error wasn't resolved. I also tried declaring a0 and a1 outside the `def` but that stopped code from running altogether.

Putting `return` under while is not working as well.

I have no idea what else to do. Any help will be appreciated. (Extremely sorry if this resembles some other post, i.e. looks like a duplicate)

Comment: Your codeblock doesn't make sense at all, please indent it correctly

Comment: are you sure about indentation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the problem. You need to use an `eval` statement in place of the `list`.

Assuming this would not be exploited,

Change `list(input("Enter x variables: "))` to `eval(input("Enter x variables: "))`.

Do the same for `y` as well.

`list` made a list of each character in the user input. `eval`, in this case, parses the list of numbers.

Try `print`ing the lists before passing them to the function.

If you don't want to use `eval`, have the user `input` the length of the list. Then, use a `for` loop to enter each value, one at a time.

Like this:

```
xx = []
length = int(input("Enter length of xx: "))
for i in range(length):
    xx.append(int(input(f"Enter xx[{i}]: ")))
```

Yet another (more complicated) way to do this, which you may find useful:

```
xx = list(map(lambda x: int(x), input("Enter x variables: ").split(" ")))
```

This splits the input string into a list of number-strings. The `map` function converts each element of that list into integers. Then the final result is converted back to a list (`map()` returns a `map` object)

Comment: Thanks a ton. I've been trying to do it for almost 2 hours now and the other answers didn't make much of a change(other than 2 downvotes lol). But I have a few doubts, first: Why does it work when xx and yy are declared (as a list) inside the code itself and not asked by the user. Like in the code written by @Roman. Second, is there any way to avoid ',' while inputting the numbers because you don't have to put ',' while inputting a list?

Comment: Answering your first question, the input list was not being parsed correctly. Try printing the list after the input() function to see what I mean. Answering your second, if you don't want to input square brackets or commas, then I would suggest to split the input string using spaces as the separator. @Roman Ferenets suggested this method.

Comment: I just modified my answer to be more concise and, hopefully, even more useful to you.

Answer (score 0):

`a0` and `a1` is only defined inside the `if`, but the function attempts to return them even if the `if` is not entered. You could either declare them before the `if` or return some default value that isn't depended on `a0` and `a1` if the `if` is not entered.

Comment: Sorry, the indentation wasn't correct. Kindly have a look again.

Comment: Still looks like `a0` and `a1` ae defined inside the `if`, but the `return` isn't. What am I missing?

Comment: Nothing I guess, but now it returns the default values for `a0` and `a1` even though `len(x)>3`

Comment: Sorry but I am not sure how to. I can edit the one in the original post to the latest and you may copy.

Comment: I must add that I tried declaring them before `def` too, but then the code doesn't run.

Comment: Can you explain why the result printed were the default values for `a0` and `a1` even when the argument of `for` was true?

Answer (score 0):

I guess I've managed to understand what's the problem.You are literally passing list to input like so:

```
Enter x variables:1 2 3 4
...
```

Of course you are having an error because your input is parsed like this:

```
['1', ' ', '2', ' ', '3', ' ', '4']
```

You can pass inputs this way:

```
Enter x variables:4 5 6 7
Enter y variables:10 12 14 16
```

Then parse them like this:

```
xx=list(map(lambda x: float(x), (input("Enter x variables:")).split(' ')))
yy=list(map(lambda x: float(x), (input("Enter y variables:")).split(' ')))
```

Or use any other separator which you prefer.

Comment: Indeed it does. The problem occurs when I try to take the input from the user. Also, I corrected the indentation.

Comment: @Samarth What do you enter in prompt?

Comment: `xx=[4,5,6,7]` `yy=[10,12,14,16]` i.e. same as mentioned.

Comment: @Samarth You cannot pass list like this to input.They will be parsed incorrectly.

Comment: No! The square brackets were just to make clear what I was talking about. I entered `Enter x variables: 4 5 6 7`. The same goes for the y variable. I didn't put any commas or brackets while entering.

Comment: Thanks a lot!. But now it's showing `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +=: 'int' and 'str'` for line 10 which wasn't the problem before. Can you explain why that happened?

Comment: @Samarth, sorry forgot that list values should be converted into ints or floats.Edited my answer, should work fine now.